# Magento Cron wont work

Tags: magento, cron, cpanel, jobs

I can't the cron job i've set up in Cpanel to pull order conformations through. All the orders are being held in the database and Orders are set to send a duplicate to my email in the backend. Is this cron command correct? Have set it to every 5 minutes.

```
 php -f /home/myusername/public_html/cron.php
```

Using magento 1.9.

Comment: We can't really know whether it is correct because we don't know whether your PHP interpreter is installed correctly, whether the path to the file is correct, etc. What happens - does it not run at all?

Comment: I believe it is installed correctly. We have two websites set up identically and one is fine the other isn't. I don't believe so. Is there a way I can check?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: What's your cron expression ? make it  */5 * * * * .  Also, Make sure that cron is enabled on your server.

Comment: Thats that I've done. Yeah it is enabled.

Comment: I think it's not exclusive magento question. There're other components, such cron and php Issues.

Comment: Before test cron work, try run command on shell. 
if not show any error, serach inf error_log it's on directory. 
log /var/lig/messges show if cron it's executed
log error_log if proper setup on php.ini show php errors.

Comment: Try this http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/395-setting-up-cron-jobs-in-magento

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try to setup following cron under your account and check it.

```
*/5 *   * * *   www-data /bin/sh /path/to/magento/cron.sh cron.php -m=default
*/5 *   * * *   www-data /bin/sh /path/to/magento/cron.sh cron.php -m=always
```

Comment: That is not an answer is correct. You do not know which model Apache + PHP uses or uses that distribution client to see if www-data is the executor of the script.